# Control player z axis with mouse x axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move the player to the position of the mouse in my game.
Right now movement along the x axis works fine, but I want the mouse y axis to control the characters movement along the z axis (because of my top-down camera's y being world z).

Right now mouse y controls player y, [which looks like this in game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3whzY.gif)

And the code for it looks like this:

```
public Vector2 mousePos;
private Vector3 playerPos;

void update()
{
    // Get mouse position from player
    mousePos = Input.mousePosition;

    // Move player with mouse
    playerPos = new Vector3(mousePos.x, 0, mousePos.y);
    transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(playerPos);
}
```

I then tried to just swap the y and z like this

```
playerPos = new Vector3(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, 0);
```

But instead of allowing me to control the z axis this snippet instead causes the player to lose all movement.

I'm very new to coding so I might be missing something completely obvious. What am I doing wrong?

Unity version: 2018.4.21f1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you gave isn't working because you're providing a z coordinate of 0 and when called on a perspective camera, `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` does some vector math, so in your scene view, your player is probably floating right on top of your camera. I can't explain the actual math because I don't understand it, but luckily for both of us, we don't need to! Essentially, the z coordinate is saying how far away from the camera to place the point, and since the view frustum of a perspective camera gets narrower closer to the camera, placing it at 0 means there's nowhere for it to go. [image: You can see here] how moving the object farther from the camera requires it to move farther to match the mouse position.

The bigger problem is that your method is wrong and there's a better way. `Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint` converts a mouse coordinate to a world space coordinate depending on what the camera is looking at, so you're essentially flippng the y and z coordinate, then feeding it into a method that figures out what coordinates need to be flipped.

It looks like this script is attached to your player gameObject, so it should look like this:

```
Camera cam;
[Range(1,10)]  //this just creates a slider in the inspector
public int distanceFromCamera;

void Start()
{
    //calling Camera.main is a shortcut for 
    //FindGameObjectsWithTag("MainCamera")
    //so you should avoid calling it every frame
    cam = Camera.main;
}

void Update()
{
    //This will work for both perspective and orthographic cameras
    transform.position = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(
        Input.mousePosition + new Vector3(0,0,distanceFromCamera));
}
```

If your camera is going to move closer or farther from the plane, make sure to add something that keeps the distance from camera updated.

That said, for most games having the player tied to the mouse cursor isn't usually what you're looking for. Generally you want some kind of input to move the player in some direction a certain amount. If that's what you're looking for, [this part of the space shooter tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVSLczG1M1E) is a good introduction to player movement (though the code itself may be outdated).

Comment: Thank you! [This solved my problem](https://imgur.com/a/8RW3VPV).   </br>If anyone else uses this code and finds their character [too high into the air](https://imgur.com/a/1wlahPc) all you need to do is change the value of the Range in the second line to increase the range of the slider. I will take a look at the tutorial to find the conventional way of implementing this mechanic.

Comment: Ah yeah I should have explained that. I just put the range attribute there for demonstration purposes. The distance to the camera should be set to whatever the distance is between the camera and the place you want your character. If the camera will be moving, you can set/update it in code.